# New to Salesforce and still training, but need help with Validation Rule

Tags: validation-rule

Course name, Duration, Course Fee and category fields are all mandatory, but duration for (Java) picklist value under course name field should not be mandatory.

The validation rule I currently have is and Duration is still showing mandatory for Java:

```
INOT(ISPICKVAL(Course_Name__c , 'Java' ))
&&  
ISNULL('Duration')
```

Answer (score 2):

The most basic version of that formula would be:

```
Not(IsPickVal(Course_Name__c, 'Java')) && IsBlank(Duration__c)
```

Which says that "If course name is not Java, and Duration is blank, show an error."

For the other fields that are always required, simply mark them as required on the page layout so the users have an expectation of which fields are required.

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

```
(
    NOT(ISPICKVAL(Course_Name__c,"Java")) 
    && ISBLANK(Duration_Of_Hours__c )
)
|| ISBLANK( TEXT(Course_Name__c ) )
|| ISNULL( Course_Fees__c ) 
|| ISBLANK( TEXT( Category__c ) )
```